# Matplotlib -- UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left == right == 737342.0 results in singular transformations;

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

By Using Matplotlib i am trying to create a Line chart but i am facing below issue. Below is the code. Can someone help me with any suggestion

```
Head = ['Date','Count1','Count2','Count3']

df9 = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=Head)

df9.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

df9.plot(ax=ax)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(SATURDAY))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %d'))

plt.legend()
plt.xticks(fontsize= 15)
plt.yticks(fontsize= 15)
plt.savefig(Line.png)
```

i am getting below error

```
Error: Matplotlib UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left == right == 737342.0 results in singular transformations; automatically expanding (ax.set_xlim(left, right))
```

Sample Data:

```
01-10-2010, 100, 0 , 100
```

X Axis: I am trying to display date on base of date every saturdays
Y Axis: all other 3 counts

Can some one please help me whats this issue and how can i fix this...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200677/discussion-on-question-by-ravi-matplotlib-userwarning-attempting-to-set-iden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that somehow, `pandas.DataFrame.plot` explicitly sets the x- and y- limits of your plot to the limits of your data. This is normally fine, and no one notices. In fact, I had a lot of trouble finding references to your warning anywhere at all, much less the Pandas bug list.

The workaround is to set your own limits manually in your call to `DataFrame.plot`:

```
if len(df9) == 1:
    delta = pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    lims = [df9.index[0] - delta, df9.index[0] + delta]
else:
    lims = [None, None]
df9.plot(ax=ax, xlim=lims)
```

Comment: @May i can know how the  Timedelta works?  because now the complete Chart is empty with no data

Comment: @Ravi. FWIW, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28905

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also arise in a more tricky situation, when you do NOT only have one point, but only one cat get on your plot : Typically, when only one point is >0 and your plot yscale is logarithmic.

One should always set limits on a log scale when there 0 values. Because, there is no way the program can decide on a good scale lower limit.